# Nodes must be provided

Tags: java

I am having trouble saving my YAML file. I have an NPE while nothing is null.

I use this backup method over several times and have never encountered this error. I tried debugging but nothing works.

```
public void sendMail(List<SendMail> mails, boolean notify)
{
    for(SendMail mail : mails)
    {
        int id = getMailIndex(mail.getUuid()) + 1;
        Map<Integer, Mail> m = getAllMailFor(UUID.fromString(mail.getUuid()));
        if(mail != null) {
            m.put(id, new Mail(id, mail.item, mail.getExp()));
            this.mails.remove(UUID.fromString(mail.getUuid()));
            this.mails.put(UUID.fromString(mail.getUuid()), m);
        }
        String path = mail.getUuid() + "." + id;
        config.getMailYAML().set(path + ".item", mail.getItem());
        config.getMailYAML().set(path + ".time", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
        config.getMailYAML().set(path+".exp", mail.getItem());
        if(path == null) System.out.println("PATH");
        if(config.getMailYAML().get(path+".item") == null) System.out.println("ITEM");
        if(config.getMailYAML().get(path+".time") == null) System.out.println("TIME");
        if(config.getMailYAML().get(path+".exp") == null) System.out.println("EXP");
        incrementMailIndex(mail.getUuid());
        if (notify) {
            Player reciever = this.instance.getServer().getPlayer(UUID.fromString(mail.getUuid()));
            if (reciever != null){
                reciever.sendMessage(this.instance.getHDVPrefix() + "§7Vous avez reçu un mail §e/hdv mail");
                reciever.playSound(reciever.getLocation(), Sound.BLOCK_NOTE_PLING, 10, 10);
            }
        }
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(HDV.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                config.saveMail();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Nodes must be provided.
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.NodeTuple.<init>(NodeTuple.java:28) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representMapping(BaseRepresenter.java:163) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.SafeRepresenter$RepresentMap.representData(SafeRepresenter.java:306) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlRepresenter$RepresentConfigurationSection.representData(YamlRepresenter.java:23) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:94) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representMapping(BaseRepresenter.java:156) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.SafeRepresenter$RepresentMap.representData(SafeRepresenter.java:306) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:94) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.represent(BaseRepresenter.java:64) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.dumpAll(Yaml.java:242) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.dumpAll(Yaml.java:206) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.dump(Yaml.java:181) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration.saveToString(YamlConfiguration.java:39) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration.save(FileConfiguration.java:68) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at com.elenox.hdv.manager.ConfigManager.saveMail(ConfigManager.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at com.elenox.hdv.manager.HDVManager$5.run(HDVManager.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:52) [Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

Line HDVManager:207

```
config.saveMail();
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the method that has thrown the NPE is this:

```
public NodeTuple(Node keyNode, Node valueNode) {
    if (keyNode == null || valueNode == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Nodes must be provided.");
    }
    this.keyNode = keyNode;
    this.valueNode = valueNode;
}
```

As you can see, the constructor is saying that it has been called with an invalid (`null`) argument.

Looking further up the stack trace, and doing a bit more digging, it looks like something is calling the YAML serializer with a Bukkit `Configuration` object that is malformed; e.g. it has a `null` instead of a key or value.

Your should be able to figure out whether it is a key or a value that is `null` using the debugger.

---

> I have an NPE while nothing is null.

That is plainly not true.  As you can see from the code above, that exception with that message is being thrown because there is a `null`.

A more correct statement would be that you have not found the `null` that is causing the problem.  Yet.  Keep looking.